# Use another Jenkins plugin from my plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm writing a Jenkins plugin that has some complex logic for sending slack notifications - more than just "build failed", or "build succeeded".  Within my plugin, I'd like to use the slacksend plugin to send slack messages.  How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

In the pom.xml of your plugin, declare a dependency on the plugin you want to use. In youd code, use classes from the dependency. You'll find groupId, artifactId and version here:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/slack-plugin/blob/master/pom.xml

You'll also want to add this section, as Jenkins plugins are not available in Maven Central.

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
            <url>http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
            <url>http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```